# How does Collector's Vessel from Unearthed Arcana interact with Ranged: Self spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, unearthed-arcana, targeting

Collector's Vessel, the [Noble Genie Warlock Patron](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020-Subclasses01.pdf#page=4)'s first level ability from Unearthed Arcana, can let a warlock link themselves with another creature, enabling them to cast spells from the bound creature's space.

Does this allow them to cast, say, *[armor of agathys](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/armor-of-agathys)* on their ally? Or can they only cast spells that do not have a range of Self through this link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You can cast from that space, but can't change who is affected

You didn't quote any of the relevant text, but this is the feature you seem to be talking about:

> While you are tethered to a creature, you gain the following benefits:
>
> •You gain a bonus to your Wisdom (Perception) checks equal to your Charisma modifier (minimum of +1).
>
> •**When you can cast a spell, you can deliver the spell from your space or the bound creature’s space**

This does not change the target of the spell, simply the location the spell is coming from. So for your Armor of Agathys spell, you can still only cast it on yourself, not on your ally.

So you'd be able to cast touch-based and ranged spells as if you were standing in that spot instead, but it'll do absolutely nothing for what kind of targets your spells can target, only where you're casting the spell from.

The only type of range: self spells that should realistically allow this kind of interaction are spells like Burning Hands, that create a cone shape with 'range self'. These will, obviously, cast from the linked creature's location instead. This is something entirely different from trying to cast a spell that only targets yourself on that target.

Comment: So if you cast a Self spell from the bound creatures space, it still only affects you? That seems a bit unclear in your answer (Or I'm not reading it correctly).

Comment: @JohnP: I think Theik's point is that the feature changes the origin of the spell, but not the target. So if the target is "self" it can affect only _you_, regardless of anything else. So this feature would simply be redundant.

Comment: Strictly, many spells have targets of "self" because the caster is used as the origin for the area effect it actually produces. I don't think it is intended that those spells are not compatible with this ability.

Comment: Intention doesn't matter. RAW, if a spell targets self then it only affects the caster. Some abilities specifically mention that when you cast a spell that targets self then...something (e.g. can also affect your familiar). But since the Collector's Vessel doesn't mention that, then it does only what it says (bearing in mind this is UA, not official).

Comment: And just to clarify my previous comment: _you_ are still the caster, regardless of where the spell is delivered from, since the feature specifically says "When _you_ cast a spell..."

Comment: Tried to clarify a bit, also included an example of a range:self spell that should realistically work with this feature, although I'm dubious on if the RAW works out 100%. Either way, there's no way you're targetting armor of agathys on somebody else.